# How do you change the Python version used in Wing IDE 101?

Tags: python

I upgraded Python from version 2.6.6 to version 3.2, however, my WING IDE still uses version 2.6.6. I tried changing the Python executable under Edit --> Configure Python (and linking to the python.exe under C:/Python32), but that didn't seem to work even after a WING restart... Any help is appreciated, thank you.

This is on Windows XP, by the way.

Comment: Which version of WING? Did you change the project settings to use the different version of Python also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working right now with Wingware WingIDE and Python 3.2.2, so it is possible, using exactly the method you mentioned. Your problem must be elsewhere. Try updating Python and Wingware to their last versions.